# How do I remove myself from Retrocomputing @ StackExchange?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I would like to remove myself from this community so how do I do it? I can't find anything in the Help Center [sic] but perhaps I'm searching for the wrong expression.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to close your account completely, that can only be done by the SE staff.

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/236563) is the explanation and it has a link to a [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Complete the form and wait for the process to take its course.
Your profile will be removed from the system.

We'll be sorry to see you go.

Comment: Are you just being polite as I haven't contributed anything useful.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Yes you have! You've asked questions, provided answers, shared knowledge and code... You haven't posted lots, but that doesn't mean that it's not useful. Thanks for contributing what you have. I hope that we can keep it on the site even if you close your account, but the SE staff might delete it if you _really_ don't want it to stay.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers:. Don't​ do yourself down.  You have made positive, welcome contributions to the site.  Please don't depart in haste.

Comment: Incidentally, if your account is deleted, your posts are not.  They effectively become anonymous.